# javascript subtracting date numbers from each other

Tags: php, javascript

I'm passing a date in this format; YYYY-MM-DD as a php variable to a javascript function.

however when i get it in the js function - its gone ahead and subtracted the numbers

```
//php
$today = "2013-05-30";
onclick="myjsfunction($today)"

//js
function myjsfunction(today)
{
alert(today);
}
```

this give 1978 (2013 minus 5 minus 30) !

anyone know a way round this?

thanks

Comment: **[Seems to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/S6G2q/)**

Comment: hmm, yea but its still not working on mine

Comment: print $today variable value in php ,
i think is not given right value .

Comment: when i print it in php it says: 2013-05-30

Comment: ok , so you should pass like 
onclick="myjsfunction('"+$today+"')";

Comment: just tried it, but doesnt like it. i've realised that the variable passed through as parameter to js function cant have any spaces, minus signs or anything like that. So $data = "hey you"; can't be passed through into js function - is this normal or is there something wrong my side?

Comment: Read the last comment before yours again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

`$today = "\"2013-05-30\"";`

Or

`$today = "'2013-05-30'";`

Or, even better:

```
//php
$today = "2013-05-30";
onclick="myjsfunction('$today')"
```

The idea is that the result of `echo (onclick);` have to be `myjsfunction('2013-05-30')` or `myjsfunction("2013-05-30")` for the parameter to be handled like a string insted of an integer (result of 2013 minus 5 minus 30).

Comment: thanks - tired it but then js doesnt like it and it wont compute

Comment: Have you checked what is outputed in your html page? With the code in your question, onclick probably results in `myjsfunction(2013-05-30);`. You want it to be `myjsfunction("2013-05-30");` or `myjsfunction('2013-05-30');`, so the parameter is a string.

Comment: It's treating them as integers because they are not properly escaped. You need to ensure that PHP is adding quotes so JS know it's meant as a string not a group of integers.

Comment: yes. thanks, it was just a case of having to put ' on eitherside of the string parameter going into the function - all the other paramteres were integers so didnt need them - im such an idiot - thanks